# MySQL ConnectionString " No Database Selected"

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

i'm currently trying to do a mysql tool in c# for exporting data out of my database.

I hardcoded the mysql.Connectionstring with:

`private MySqlConnection _conn;
mycon = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=tools;pwd=tools;database=t_data;";
_conn.ConnectionString = mycon;`

This fully work without a problem. But as u know u want it editable. So i created 3 Textboxes in my Form. Added a class.

When i hit export i assign the textbox values into my class

```
        StringExporter.user.ip = textBox1.Text;
        StringExporter.user.usr = textBox2.Text;
        StringExporter.user.pwd = textBox3.Text;
        StringExporter.user.db = textBox4.Text;
```

Thats my class

```
public static class user
{
    public static string ip;
    public static string usr;
    public static string pwd;
    public static string db;

}
```

But every time i want to export i get an Mysql error that no database is selected and i dont get why. I outputed all the string and they are fully fine.

Would be cool if someone could help me with that :)

Comment: Could you post the entire code that you are using to export data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to re-create the connection string. If that is the case, it should be simple. Update the connection string and then execute your insert, update, select or delete

```
try{
    mycon = "server="+user.ip+";uid="+user.usr+";pwd="+user.pwd+";database="+user.db+";"
    _conn.ConnectionString = mycon;
    _conn.Open();
    //Do your stuff
    _conn.Close();
} catch(Exception e){ MessageBox.Show("Failed due to :" + e.Message); }
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i want to do. I already did the thing u mentioned with: mycon2 = "server=" + StringExporter.user.ip + ";uid=" + StringExporter.user.usr + ";pwd=" + StringExporter.user.pwd + ";database=" + StringExporter.user.db + ";"; but i got the error "No database selected" /////////////// I also cant acces the string with user.ip only with StringExporter.user.ip

Comment: OK. "No database selected" is your custom error message I assume. Please paste the exception error message you are facing...

Comment: http://grabilla.com/05408-358cd773-7b0d-4730-a3eb-07b93b6490f1.png Thats the error

Comment: OK. Please take and share a screenshot without the error popup.. So, I will check your code.

Comment: http://grabilla.com/05408-9f788c6e-b8c9-4352-b1b7-1fb1209ea668.png code without error

Comment: Your code seems fine. Try to add "USE <database_name>;" in start of the query.

Comment: On other possible reason is your "StringExporter.user.db" could be empty string. Add a breakpoint and check if the value exists. You said you have added 3 textboxes.. I guess it is supposed to be 4 textboxes.

Comment: The string is right, checked that with a message box // http://grabilla.com/05408-67078a2d-5963-48b8-bfdc-c099e5ed71fb.png sry ofc i added 4 textboxes <.< my mistake

Comment: If mycon equals mycon2 then you should not have any problem!! logically!!

Comment: After all i got it myself :D Thx for the help